# Does the size of objects drawn by openGL affect the performance?

Tags: java, opengl

When I draw stuff with OpenGL, I wanted to know how the size reflects upon the performance. Does it get slower the bigger the numbers get? I would think yes but I do not really know.

For example, when I tell OpenGL to draw something from -1 to 1 would it take more time to draw something from -10 to 10 or doesn't it matter that much?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of an object itself, meaning the coordinates it has, have no impact on the performance. What matters is the size the object has on screen. When an object covers a larger number of pixels, then the fragment shader has to be executed more often and more pixels have to be written to the buffer.

Comment: Thanks! Another question, not really on topic but you mentionned the fragemt shader.. Do I have to interact with the fragment shader in order to get rid of anything drawn to the screen, like clear the buffer where all pixels are being stored.. I'm not really familliar with shaders and I'm having trouble erasing stuff that has been drawn to the screen..

Comment: thanks but found a way now, I just had to clear the arrayList where all my objects are being stored in, it was acutally very simple :)